# Color table for just Windows 10 Universal apps

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Could someone point me to a link that has the available colors for configuring Windows 10 xaml properties.

I have tried all sorts of searches on google even images but just want the list that is pertinent to Windows 10 xaml properties not every color on the windows platform.

Sorry if its a dumb question and will delete it if moderatars as me to but I have just about finished updated windows 8 apps to the one windows 10 app but need to be able to get the right color scheme going that works in with the same apps on the other stores.

OR is there a tool that gives that help.  I will keep looking and did try and look at the ThemeResource idea but am finding it hard to find that information too.   AND yes I have been looking for some time.

Come to think of it, I just need to be able to see the colors of just the windows 10 xaml properties in a table.  Really simple request I know but I am at a loss as to where to find it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by available colors? Technically you could use pretty much whatever RGB hex color value or name you want. Or do you mean like the [theme resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187274.aspx#the_xaml_color_ramp_and_theme-dependent_brushes)?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response, yes thats it but I just need to see the colors so I can make a design choice that works in with the existing color schemes for the same app on the other store.  I did not know I could use RGB values for the background.  SO if you were to use a custom colour for say a Textblock background="RGB" value, how can you do it as I have tried but failed todate?

Comment: Eh, I mean there's multiple ways. If you wanted you could just open a hex [color picker](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp?colorhex=191970) in your browser and grab the value, or like I said, just select the object and in your properties pane there should be a color picker for anything that supports Fill/Background. Then it's just a matter of picking your color and letting VS plop it in there for ya or typing it out like `Background="#FF0000"` or apply an alpha channel opacity if you want too like `Background="#57FF0000"`

Comment: Thats it.  For some reason I did not try that but should of as now I feel stupid for asking it.  I will post an answer incase there are other folk out there suffering the same brain freeze I am.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a brain freeze and for some reason did not try the follow that works just fine.  Hope this answer helps someone.

```
              <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid Background="#FF0000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="40" >
                    <TextBlock Text="FF0000" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```

Thanks Chris for the help.